# How to sort a 2D list first using 1st column in increasing order, then by 2nd column in decreasing order in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a 2D list first using 1st column in increasing order, then by 2nd column in decreasing order. For eg a list ([3,1],[1,6],[1,4],[2,8],[2,1]) should be sorted as ([1,6],[1,4],[2,8],[2,1],[3,1]).
It would be good if you can tell how to sort this using sorted function in python.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use key function `lambda k: (k[0], -k[1])` That means sort by first item in ascending order, second item in descending order:

```py
lst = [[3, 1], [1, 6], [1, 4], [2, 8], [2, 1]]

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda k: (k[0], -k[1])))
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 6], [1, 4], [2, 8], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
```